# AWS Instance not able to connect to itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, telnet

I have just started playing with AWS, but I have created an instance and when I try to install some software that talks to a specific port, it doesn't go anywhere.

Here is what I am trying to do:

> [root@ip-172-31-16-22 logs]# telnet 172.31.16.22 9011
>   Trying 172.31.16.22...
>   telnet: connect to address 172.31.16.22: Connection timed out

This is the result of netstat -an:

> Active Internet connections (servers and established)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9011                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

As you can see, the host is clearly listening on port 9011. I then thought it might have been something to do with my AWS Security Group, but I have the following inbound rule:

> Custom TCP Rule TCP 9011 0.0.0.0/0

and the following outbound rule:

> All Traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

As far as I can tell, it should work, but it doesn't. I have set up a Flow Log and when I run the telnet, it doesn't show any traffic from the instance to itself. I have also stopped the iptables firewall in case it was the culprit, but it didn't make any difference.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Bertrand.

Comment: let's see ``netstat -rn`` for a bit of local routing table.  Also, is netcat installed?  Some versions of netcat have a "scan for listening" option.  On my system the command would be ``nc -vz localhost 9001``

Comment: also, is this inside a VPC? Is the network a private network?

Comment: @mircea: thanks a lot for the question. Yes, it is inside a VPC and it is a private network.

Comment: @Vorsprung here is the output of netstat -rn : `[root@ip-172-31-16-22 ~]# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
[root@ip-172-31-16-22 ~]# ` . Let me see what I can do on the netcat. I don't believe it is installed yet.

Comment: @Vorsprung I have run `nc -vz localhost 9011` and it doesn't return anything.  I have also tried to run `nc -vz 172.31.16.22 9011` with the same result.

Comment: is it possible that you have a firewall running on the machine?

Comment: does telnet 0.0.0.0 9011 work?

Comment: @mircea  `ifconfig -a`: `[vagrant@ip-172-31-16-22 ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:FB:8E:CD:48:1F  
          inet addr:172.31.16.22  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fb:8eff:fecd:481f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:367312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:343436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:319849998 (305.0 MiB)  TX bytes:23663905 (22.5 MiB)
          Interrupt:164 `

Comment: and `lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          LOOPBACK  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
` I have tried `telnet 0.0.0.0 9011`, but 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address, so it failed. I have iptables running on the box, but I shut it down and got the same result, so I don't think it is iptables.

Answer (score 0):

If by "flow log" you mean a VPC flow log then attaching via the localhost to itself will not show up in the flow logs.

The internal Linux routing will automatically send the packets via the local network stack and they won't leave the box

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I figured as much, but just wanted to make sure that the packets weren't going outside. It still doesn't explain why I can't do `telnet 172.31.16.22 9011`.